# Ergodicity of stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

If one can show that the process converges to a stationary process in probability, does it mean that the process is ergodic?

Answer (score 0):

If a process converges to a "unique" stationary process, then it should be ergodic. But as you say it converges to a stationary process in probability, it should also imply that it is unique and therefore ergodic as well.

Comment: ok thanks! but then I do not understand why then every stationary process is not ergodic? I mean every stationary process definitely converges in probability to a stationary process (itself)